# Change Checkbox Label in Bootstrap Based on Screen Size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.2.0, and I have a checkbox with the label: **Show hidden posts**.

On small screens (xs) I would like the label to be **Show Hidden** to save some screen space.

Can I do this within Bootstrap? Do I need to use JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the word **Posts** in a `hidden-xs`

```
    Show Hidden <span class="hidden-xs">Posts</span>
```

Comment: Awesome, for some reason I didn't think that would work for a checkbox label, but it does. Thank you.